# how to use object inside object array in obj c

Tags: objective-c, arrays, object

I have an object array set up like this:

```
NSMutableArray *image_view_array;
IBOutlet UIImageView *image_view_1, *image_view_2, *image_view_2;
```

and:

```
image_view_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];
[image_view_array addObject:image_view_1];    
[image_view_array addObject:image_view_2];
[image_view_array addObject:image_view_3];
```

how can i access the image of the image view array?
I tried these:

```
image_view_array[0].image
[image_view_array objectAtIndex:0].image
```

but it doesn't work.
Thank You!

Comment: What error do you get when you say it doesn't work?

Comment: where in the code is each of this code fragments located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to cast it back to UIImageView:

```
((UIImageView *)[image_view_array objectAtIndex:0]).image
```

The NSArray doesn't preserve type, so everything you pull out will be an NSObject as far as the compiler knows.  So you as the programmer have to cast it back to the type put in.

Comment: Actually, everything you pull out of the array will be `id`, not `NSObject *`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of casting you can send a message, as objects typed `id` do accept every message and objects in arrays are hold as `id`.

```
UIImage *img = [image_view_array[0] image];
```

Answer (score 1):

Two lines are more readable and easier to debug:

```
UIImageView *imageView = image_view_array[0];
UIImage *image = imageView.image;
```

BTW - learn to use standard naming conventions. Camel case is preferred over using underscores.

Name your array as `imageViewArray` and your outlets as `imageView1` and `imageView2`.